# How do I view the Jenkins server console output on the local filesystem?

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

I'm using the Jenkins Active Directory plug-in and can't log in after several attempts.
The error message says:

`If you are a system administrator and suspect this to be a configuration problem, see the server console output for more details.`

Where can I find the server console output (on the local filesystem)?

I presume that it is accessible from the Jenkins web pages, but since I can't log in, that's not much use. I *can* log in to the (Windows) server where Jenkins is installed - where are they on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console output you are looking for are not accessible from Jenkins.  If you have installed Jenkins as a service, when that service is started three files are created in JENKINS_HOME: jenkins.err.log, jenkins.out.log, and jenkins.wrapper.log.  The relevant ones for you are jenkins.err.log and jenkins.out.log.
If you used the default location you can find them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins.

Comment: Not accessible from Jenkins? What's different from what's shown at `/log/all`?

Comment: If you compare what is in these files with what `/log/all` yields you'll notice there are differences.
I urge you to read the [Jenkins Logging wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions you can tail the logs under `$JENKINS_HOME/support/all_[date].log`. It outputs all relevant information when you're modifying settings on the Web console and such.